# Python real time edge detection - get number of white pixel from every frame

Tags: python, image, opencv, pixel, detection

I am using the following python code from GitHub for edge detection in real time:

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 

while 1: 

     ret, frame = cap.read() 

     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
  
     lower_red = np.array([5,50,50]) 
     upper_red = np.array([15,255,255]) 
  
     mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) 

     res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask) 

     cv2.imshow('Original',frame) 

     edges = cv2.Canny(frame,100,200) 

     cv2.imshow('Edges',edges) 

     k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
     if k == 27: 
         break

 cap.release()

 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to get the number of black and white pixels in every frame and print this values.
I can do this for example via the following code for 1 picture:

```
from PIL import Image
import operator

img = Image.open("1.png").convert('1')

black, white = img.getcolors()
print(black[0])
print(white[0])
```

Can somebody help matching this two code sections, so I can print the number of white pixels from every frame?
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Use OpenCv's [countNonZero](https://www.docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914) to count the number of white pixels, like this: `numberOfWhitePixels = cv2.countNonZero(binaryImage)`. To get the number of black pixels, simply subtract this number from the total pixels in the image. Hint: You can get the total number of pixels of an image by looking at its `size`.